# Signals and slots between objects in different threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Basically, I've the next code:

```
 class serverTCP : public QObject
 {
      // Other methods...

      signals:
           void newInstructions(QJsonDocument jDoc);

      public slots:
           void responseObtained(QJsonDocument jDoc);
 }

 class gatherModbus : public QObject
 {
      // Other methods...

      signals:
           void responseReady(QJsonDocument jDoc);

      public slots:
           void executeInstruction(QJsonDocument jDoc);
           void myprocess() {
                while(true)
                {
                     // Write and read Serial Port
                     // Save data in json 
                }
           };
 }

 void main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
      QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
      int netsNumber = 2; //In reality this is dynamic. It's only a example
      serverTCP *server = new serverTCP;
      gatherModbus * gather = new gatherModbus[netsNumber];
      QThread * threads = new QThread[netsNumber];

      // more necessary code...

      for(int i = 0; i < netsNumber; i++)
      {
           gather[i].moveToThread(threads[i]);

           QObject::connect(&server, SIGNAL(newInstructions(QJsonDocument)),
                            &gather[i], SLOT(executeInstruction(QJsonDocument)));

           QObject::connect(&gather[i], SIGNAL(responseReady(QJsonDocument)),
                            &server, SLOT(responseObtained(QJsonDocument)));

           QObject::connect(&threads[i], SIGNAL(start()), 
                            &gather[i], SLOT(myprocess()));

           // Other signals needed between the objects 'gather' and 'threads'

           threads[i].start();
      }

      a.exec();
 }
```

The problem is that the connections between objects 'server' and 'gather' do not work. The object 'server' is in the same thread as the 'main' function but objects 'gather' have moved to other threads.

**What have I to do to make both objects can communicate properly?**

My purpose is that the 'server' must be able to send a signal to all objects 'gather' there are. In each of the objects 'gather' must execute the slot and return the 'server' response if any.

If I set up the connection to be the type `Qt::DirectConnection` slots running on the same thread as the 'main' function and object 'server' and that does not interest me.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see where `void myprocess()` is called. If it is not, please remove from the code sample

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten to put the connection start signal threads to "myprocess" method.

Answer (score 0):

**All is in Qt documentation.**
First, read [**that**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).
Then if you're not satisfied, you can use **`QCoreApplication::postEvent()`** (for more informations you need : **[here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html)**)

Both signals/slots (`QObject:connect()`) and `QCoreApplication::postEvent()` are **thread-safe** and can solve your problem.

So events and signal/slots are two parallel mechanisms accomplishing the same things, in general an event will be generated by an outside entity (e.g. Keyboard, Mouswheel) and will be delivered through the event loop in QApplication. In general unless you set up the code you will not be generating events. You might filter them through `QObject::installEventFilter()` or handle events in subclassed object by overriding the appropriate functions.

Signals and Slots are much easier to generate and receive and you can connect any two QObject subclasses. They are handled through the Metaclass (have a look at your moc_classname.cpp file for more) but most of the interclass communication that you will produce will probably use signals and slots. Signals can get delivers immediately or deferred via a queue (if you are using threads) A signal can be generated

Comment: The bit the OP may be missing, is that for QueuedConnection (and AutoConnection across threads) to work, the target thread needs to have an event loop.  The Mandlebrot example in the linked documentation is likely to be the best sample.

Answer (score 0):

Your demo code seems OK. That's how we organize our current project. You'd better provide more detailed codes if necessary to explain your problem.

BTW, after reading your interests, I'd recommend you the QtConcurrent module which seems fitting your interest better.

Answer (score 0):

Huh... Your code is not ok. This is the source of all your trouble

```
void myprocess() {
      while(true)
      {
          // Write and read Serial Port
          // Save data in json 
       }
};
```

If you want the slots `newInstructions` and `responseObtained` slots to ever run, myprocess should not be an infinite loop. You need to :

- Modify `myprocess` such that once it is done writing and reading ***currently available data***, it completes
- Have a mechanism to know that new processing need to be done. For instance, if you are using a `QIODevice` subclass (socket, input stream, etc...) you have the signal `QIODevice::readyRead()` which will notify you there is new data to read from the device. I suspect your `newInstructions` is supposed to do just that.
- connect this mechanism to another call to `myprocess` **to allow the processing to start again**

**Edit :** Given your comment, this is a way to modify the infinite while loop without too much modification.

```
void myprocess() {
      make_one_processing_round();
      if(should_continue_processing())
      {
          QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, &gatherModbus::myprocess, Qt::QueuedConnection);
      }
};
```

[QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) will schedule this method for execution at the back of the thread QEventLoop queue. Which means other slots can execute.

Comment: The first and principal job of gatherModbus is gather data from some instruments modbus and it save the data in a json. This must run continually.

Only when the serverTCP has received a  request of data, it send a signal to gatherModbus objects. These objects analyze the message in the slot. Normally only one of this gatherModbus objects must respond.

I understand of your messages that I must change myprocess method because with this infinite loop the system can't process the events loop. Correct?

I read the Qt documentation, but sometimes I don't know how to do it.

Comment: correct. but do not use a while loop anyway. Do you ***always*** have something to read, to write?

Comment: Yes. Every some time it must read data from the instruments that 24 hours must work 365 days of year.

Comment: The question is : is there always data available? An infinite amount of data? Or Is there a time you block for incoming data?

Comment: In myprocess I do this:

1.- Send a request of data to a instrument modbus of the network.
2.- Wait to read the response.
3.-Analize the response. If it is good data, save in a json.
4.- Send a request of data to next instrument, wait to read, analize and save, etc.
5.- If the instrument is the last, back to first instrument.

I can stop the process, but I would like that the signal from serverTCP stop this process and when finished the slot execution, the process continue.

Comment: You never want to wait! The communications device object will **signal** your code when results are available. You **react** to this signal, you don't *wait* for it. You have to think that way, and invert the flow of control. The operating system wakes up the event loop when data is available, the communications class is invoked from the event loop, it processes the data and then signals your code to do its thing. **Do not write any blocking loops. They break everything and turn your code into spaghetti.**

Answer (score 0):

I can solve my problem adding the next line in the end of "myprocess" method:

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
```

The final code of this method is this:

```
void myprocess() {
            while(true)
            {
                 // Write and read Serial Port
                 // Save data in json 

                 // New line:
                 QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
            }
       };
```

With this line I get that events will processed if any. I don't known if it is the best solution, but it works as wanted.

Thanks to all of you for your help and answers.